# RSS app in iOS: Detecting the existence of a feed through UIWebView

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, rss

I'm making an RSS app.

In my "Add Feed" tab there is a UIWebView covering half of the page. I want to be able to google search or type in a website in my web view. On the other half of the page I want to have any feeds that are detected in the UIWebView to be displayed.

When the feeds/feed URL's are displayed, I want them to be next to a "plus" or "add" button. When clicked the feed is then added/saved to a UITableView in another tab.

I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me, but if anyone knows where to start or if there's a certain class that would help, please let me know! Or even a tutorial that gets me on the right track!

Here's an app that has the feature I'm talking about (the detection part) I just want to display it a different way. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-rss-reader/id290537970?mt=8

Any Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once loading is complete, fetch the HTML content of the web view:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

Use a regex or some other method to parse through the content and extract the href and title attributes of the anchor tags.

Use a heuristic to look for link titles or hrefs containing "rss", "feed", or "xml", which may indicate an RSS link.

Present the filtered list of links to your user.

Comment: So I would place all of the code to fetch the html and parse through the anchor tags in the method: `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` right? Sorry for the question within a question.

Comment: Thanks a lot though, this is already helping! If I could vote up the answer I would.

Comment: I'm having a little bit more trouble with this... I hope you're able to help!

in your suggestion you said to use `@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"` should that be the format i'm using? I'm sorry, I feel dumb asking that.

Comment: Try this sample project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13103695/RSSSubscriber.zip It's not very sophisticated, but it does everything I outlined above.

Comment: wow thank you warren! this is a huge help to look at. I don't know javascript very much at all so thanks a lot!